# Add more RAM to my MacBook Pro 5,3

Tags: macbook-pro, memory

I got my MacBook Pro on October 2009  , here are the specifications:

> Processor 2.66 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo
>   Memory 4 GB 1067 Mhz DDR3
>   Lion 10.7.3
>   15-inch, Mid 2009
>     Model Identifier: MacBookPro5,3

I want to add more RAM, hopefully add 4 GB more.

1. What are the required/recommended manufacturers?
2. Can I do it myself? Any proven guide/tutorial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1067 Mhz DDR3 is what you care about. You can do it on your own. Apple provides [instructions](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1651?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US#link1) on their website and you can find it on many places too.

For installing the RAM you just need a screwdriver small enough for the screws on the bottom of the computer. After that ground your self or use plastic gloves and take out the old memory put in the new and you are done.

Manufacturers don't matter as long as the memory is 1067 Mhz DDR3 for laptop. Its better to go for well known brands I guess such as kingston,crucial corsair etc.

I bought a Crucial Memory Kit 8GB from amazon for about £35 same type of memory with the one you need and it worked perfect.

Comment: Should I buy 8 GB one piece of 4 GB one piece (since I already have 4 GB)?

Comment: Your 4GB is most likely 2x 2GB. You can check that from 
Apple (top left of screen) > about this mac> More Info>Memory. If you have 2x 2GB buy either 1x4GB module or 2x4GB. I went with 2x 4GB.

Comment: DDR 3 1888 Mhz should do the trick? or I'm locked with 1067 Mhz?

Comment: 1888MHz is probably not even for laptop. Even if higher Mhz works, they won't be used. So even a 1333Mhz memory works on your laptop(it might not even work) it will be running at 1067 Mhz.

Comment: Sorry, my bad my bad. I mean 1333 Mhz, not 1888 Mhz

Comment: Unless you plan to move that 1333Mhz on another mac in the future, there is absolutely no reason to buy it. If you still want to buy it you need to ask the manufacturer if it will clock down to 1067Mhz. If it doesn't you won't be able to use it.

Answer (score 3):

You can check out [OWC](http://eshop.macsales.com/shop/memory/Apple_MacBook_MacBook_Pro/Upgrade). On the page itself, they have information on the RAM that's suitable for various Mac. They also have a bunch of [video tutorial](http://eshop.macsales.com/installvideos/) on the installation of RAM for different Mac model.

Answer (score 0):

I have MacBook Pro 6,2, but it uses the same 1067-DDR3 memory. I've replaced my own with Samsung memory; originally Micron memory was installed.